# Propellerhead Reason: Tutorials?

Tags: software

I just love the kind of electronic music that people create with [Propellerhead's Reason](http://www.propellerheads.se/products/reason/). I just acquired the software but I find it very difficult to use (I'm not very experienced in producing music) and would love some easy step-by-step walkthroughs to ease the learning curve a bit. Anyone got fish?

Comment: I don't know of tutorials off-hand, but as you get into it some more and have questions, please post them and we will be happy to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want free, getting started tutorials, I believe that [boyinaband.com](http://www.boyinaband.com/) and [reasonstation](http://www.reasonstation.net/tutorials/) are good starting options. Any youtube tutorial will also help with getting started with reason.

The problem is diggin' your teeth on the software. Currently I am only aware of 2 websites that provide tutorials that take advantage of Reason's most awesome features:

http://www.reason101.net/
Free tutorials, most of them are rather good and explore things that are usually forgoten by most users - like Using Thor as a Filter. Using external audio into thor for FM synthesis. Creating a Grain Synth using NXTT. Vocoding RedRum loops and other awesome things.

http://www.nucleus-soundlab.com/reason-wizardry-video-tutorials.html
There's a free tutorial about expanding the synthesis capabilites of THOR, showing that it's possible to make a Fm Synth, a Fm Modulator Synth, AM Synth (doesn't work very well), PW Synth and basically shows a new world around it.

BTW: I STRONGLY RECOMMEND watching the demo of reason wizardry, It's superb. And it's the only one that I did watch, I'm still wondering if I should pay all that money for it.

Comment: I think reason101.net was what I've been looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'll make this community wiki, so everybody can contribute.

A good start:

- [The tutorials section at reasonstation.net](http://www.reasonstation.net/tutorials/)

Answer (score 1):

The website [boyinaband.com](http://www.boyinaband.com/) has some very well explained tutorials to get you started :) It's funny too!